# Why am I gettin 'TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable'?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text editor. I am trying to add an option to open a file, but it comes up with an error for line 16. TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

root.title("Microsoft Word")

def open_file():
    file_location = ''
    file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    f = open(file_location,'r')
    x = f.read()
    f.close()
    print(x)

heading = Label(text = 'Microsoft Word', font='Helvetica 40 bold')
heading.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

text = Text()
text.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

open = Button(text = 'Open',command = open_file)
open.grid(row = 2,column = 0)

save = Button(text = 'Save')
save.grid(row = 3,column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've deleted the real `open` function and replaced it with a button.

Comment: `open = Button(text = 'Open',command = open_file)` is a bad idea because `open` is a built-in name, meaning if you try to use `open` to read a file, it'll throw an exception since you replaced that function with a `Button`. Just call it something besides `open`.

Comment: You're shadowing an in-built function (open). Try renaming the variable to something like `open_btn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you define `open` as a variable to be one of the `Button`

The problem is that `open` is a built in function and when you do that, it gets redefined to be a `Button` object.

Now when you try to open a file with the function `open`, it gives that error because `open` has been defined as a `Button`.

```
btn = Button(text = 'Open',command = open_file)
btn.grid(row = 2,column = 0)
```